# Get app name by its window ID ( in xorg & linux )

Tags: scripts, xorg, wmctrl, xprop

i have a window id, i would like to know its app name.

For example, there's an app called "PulseAudio Volume Control",  ( pavucontrol pkg )

Now if I open it and xprop it, then the wm_class etc shows `Volume Control`

Is it possible to get the actual app name mentioned in the `.desktop` file? ( the Name variable )